# Swift converting string number to decimal giving wrong result

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm trying to convert a number which is a string ("1.51") into a decimal so I can store it inside Core Data. But when I pull that decimal number back out, it's 1.50999...

Here's the code I use to convert from the string and then store.

```
priceFloat = (row[13] as NSString).floatValue
            
            newItem.royalty =  NSDecimalNumber(value: priceFloat)
```

And I display it in SwiftUI, like this...

```
 Text("\(sale.royalty ?? NSDecimalNumber(0))")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you turned it into a Float by calling `.floatValue`, you've already [applied binary rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Use the `Decimal(string:locale:)` init to convert it directly from a string to a Decimal.

Comment: Had to do "newItem.royalty = Decimal(string:row[13]) as NSDecimalNumber?" But apart from that it worked, perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI does the formatting for us and updates the labels or text fields automatically if the locale changes, it's simply `Text(sale.royalty, format: .number)` and there are many other options.